# 500 Internal Server Error Laravel 4

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have project in Laravel 4. It's on bitbucket. I've downloaded it from my repo on my local machine, crated a local virtual host, working fine. But when I cloned the same project on my server and created a virtual host, 500 Internal Server Error is shown. On same domain another virtual host for the same project in laravel 5 is working fine.

This is my virtual host file code for laravel 4 project:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName l4.mydomain
    ServerAlias l4.mydomain

    DocumentRoot /var/www/L4/public

    <Directory /var/www/L4/public/>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This is .htaccess code for laravel 4 project:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also changed the 'index.php' to 644 permission, but not worked

This is the warning and error found in log file:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/myproject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/L4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17


PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/myproject/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/L4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: Look at the apache error log. It will contain a detailed message what's wrong.

Comment: where to find apache log?

Comment: That depends on your system. Look at the apache config how `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}` is defined.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: So `/var/log/apache2/` might be a good place to look.

Comment: this the error; " HTTP/1.1" 500 205 " can you help from this?

Comment: This looks more like the access log. Please edit the complete relevant lines from the error log in your question.

Comment: This is in error log file: "PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/L4/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/L4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94812/discussion-between-mkj-and-gerald-schneider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting

`"PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/L4/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/L4/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17"`
 
in your error log, I'd say that it looks like you never ran composer install on the server.

Comment: yes you are right. I'm installing composer dependencies. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: so in which directory should I run composer install? my main Laravel directory is 'myproject'.

Comment: it should be run in your main project directory.  You should have a composer.jon file and probably a composer.lock file in that directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, this is fine now, God bless you!